# Use a custom command instead of the path itself

Tags: path, latex

In order to avoid manually editing all my paths in case I change the location of my pictures some time in the future, I would like to define paths as variables.
I define the path for my pictures with the command \def \personal_code {path/} - it works. 
But if I have different folders for my pictures, one for pictures taken in 2019, another for pictures taken in 2020, and I would like to insert them in my work using includegraphics, can I use a second \def command?
\def \personal_code1 {path1/}
\def \personal_code2 {path2/}
And then use includegraphics:
\sublloat{\includegraphics{\personal_code1 /image2019}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{\personal_code2 /image2020}}

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \def \LJpath19 {/Volumes/X/Dados/teste Latex/meas 2019/}
    %\def \LJpath20 {/Volumes/X/Dados/teste Latex/meas 2020/}
    \begin{document}
    \section{Individual graphs}
    \begin{figure}[!hbtp]
    \subfloat[PRT03]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{"\LJpath19 /22 NFA511 191219 PRT02 meas".jpg}}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \subfloat[PRT04]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{"\LJpath19 /22 NFA511 191219 PRT02 meas".jpg}}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    %\subfloat[PRT05]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{"\LJpath20 /b05 NFA711 200203 PRT07".jpg}}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the \graphicspath command? You can give a list of directories and \includegraphics search in sequence all the directories of the list. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Try with `\graphicspath{{/Volumes/X/Dados/teste Latex/meas 2019/}}` (maybe it needs some quotes because of the space, avoiding the space would be better)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but it is better to just give the name of the image without the file ending. This way latex can automatically choose the one with the best quality in case you have the same image in different formats.

Comment: \graphicspath works if I put the path between double-quotes (because of the spaces), like this: \graphicspath{{"/Volumes/X/Dados/teste Latex/meas 2019/"}}. Thanks!